# Custom deleter for shared_ptr<> giving 'no context error'

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    int val;
    void deleter(A *x)
    {
        cout << "In Delete" << endl;
    }

    void push_back(int val)
    {
        shared_ptr<A> temp = (new int(val),deleter);
        cout << temp.use_count() << endl;
    }

};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a.push_back(11);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following error.

```
test.cpp: In member function 'void A::push_back(int)':
test.cpp:17:44: error: no context to resolve type of '((A*)this)->A::deleter'
         shared_ptr<A> temp = (new int(val),deleter);
```

In General I am trying to implement a custom deleter for shared_ptr which is a member function of a nested class and I am running into horrible C++ errors. All the google examples are examples where deleter is a global function.

What am I missing here?

**Suggestion 1**:
Based on the first suggestion, I changed to the following.

```
class A;
    void deleter(A *a)
    {
        cout << "In destrcu" << endl;
    }
class A
{
    public:
    int val;

    void push_back(int val)
    {
        shared_ptr<A> temp = (new int(val),deleter);
        cout << temp.use_count() << endl;
    }

};
```

I still get this error,

```
test.cpp: In member function 'void A::push_back(int)':
test.cpp:16:43: error: conversion from 'void(A*)' to non-scalar type 'std::shared_ptr<A>' requested
         shared_ptr<A> temp = (new int(val),deleter);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off you have a couple typos/syntax errors in

```
void push_back(int val)
{
    shared_ptr<A> temp = (new int(val),deleter);
    cout << temp.use_count() << endl;
}
```

The line

```
shared_ptr<A> temp = (new int(val),deleter);
```

should be

```
shared_ptr<A> temp = shared_ptr<A>(new int(val),deleter);
//or
shared_ptr<A> temp(new int(val),deleter);
```

Then

```
new int(val)
```

is not correct since you are creating a `int*` and trying to initialize the pointer `temp` holds with that but you cant do that since `temp` holds a `A*`, not an `int*`. If you want to set the value of the `val` member then you need a constructor for `A` taking an `int`.  Having

```
A(int val) : val(val) {}
```

would let you write

```
shared_ptr<A> temp(new A(val),deleter);
```

but there is still a problem with `deleter`.  `deleter` is a non static member function which means it cannot be called without an instance of the class.  That means you either need to make `deleter` `static`, which in this case is fine since you don't need the `A` object in `deleter`.  If you need to have a non static member function then you can use a lambda to bind together an object with `deleter`.  That would look like

```
shared_ptr<A> temp(new A(val),[this](auto ptr){ deleter(ptr) }); // capture the current object
//or
A delete_obj(some_value);
shared_ptr<A> temp(new A(val),[=](auto ptr){ delete_obj.deleter(ptr) }); // captures a object for itself
```

Answer (score 2):

The deleter will be called like this by the shared pointer:

```
deleter(pointer);
```

Your deleter cannot be called like that. It must be called like this instead:

```
(object.*deleter)(pointer);
```

This is because your deleter is a pointer to a non-static member function.

Solution: Don't use a non-static member function as the deleter.

---

> ```
> void deleter(A *a)
> shared_ptr<A> temp = (new int(val),deleter);
> ```

The remaining problem is that your deleter can only delete pointers of type `A*`. But you're attempting to use it to delete a `int*`.

Comment: I changed to the function to a global function and now seeing the above error. Do I need to convert the function to a function object or something?

Comment: Thanks that helps. Even the below answer helped with the non-static member functions.